# Compute shaders : error in the initialization of textures

Tags: opengl, shader, compute-shader

I have an image2DArray in my compute shaders with 7 slices.
I can write in it with the function imageStore without problem and also display these textures.

My problem comes with the initialization, I try to initialize my textures but I can't. Indeed, I make a loop for the initialization :

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    imageStore( outputTexture , ivec3(texel, i), vec4(0));
}
```

When N = 7, nothing is displayed but when N < 7 everything works well and my textures initialized.

Is someone can explain me why I can't initialize correctly my image2DArray ?

Edit :
What I test to see that : try to write in all slices of the texture and display it. It works fine but data from the previous frame stay if I don't initialize the texture. So, I initialize all pixels of the slices to 0 but nothing display anymore if N=7.

Some code :

```
#version 430 compatibility

layout(rgba8) coherent uniform image2DArray outputTexture;
...
void main(){
    ivec2 texel = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);  
    ivec2 outSize = imageSize( outputTexture ).xy;

    if( texel.x >= outSize.x || texel.y >= outSize.y )
        return;  

    initializeMeshSet( meshSet );

    vec4 pWorld = texelFetch(gBuffer[0],texel,0);
    pWorld /= pWorld.w;
    vec4 nWorld = texelFetch(gBuffer[1],texel,0);
    nWorld /= nWorld.w;

    if( length(nWorld.xyz) < 0.1 ){
         for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            imageStore( outputTexture , ivec3(texel, i), vec4(0));
         }

        return;
    }
    if(nbFrame == 0){           
         float value = treatment(texel, pWorld, nWorld.xyz, outSize.x);
         imageStore( outputTexture, ivec3(texel, 0), vec4(vec3(value),1.0));
         imageStore( outputTexture, ivec3(texel, 1), vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0));   
    }
    else if(nbFrame == 1){
         float value = treatment2(texel, pWorld, nWorld.xyz, outSize.x);

         vec3 previousValue = imageLoad(outputTexture, ivec3(texel, 1)).xyz * (nbFrame - 1);
         value += previousValue;
         value /= nbFrame;
         imageStore( outputTexture, ivec3(texel, 1), vec4(vec3(value), 1.0));
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's too little code; show us - at least! - the genesis of `outputTexture`, pls.

Comment: I put more code, hope it will be enough to understand.

Comment: The genesis of outputTexture doesn't start in the shader; it starts with a call equivalent to glGenTextures(...) in whatever OpenGL language mapping you use.  I want to see the respective code from there up to the respective glUniform call.